# Display list vertically in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce, list

I have an inputText field in which I want to display a String list.The list diplay horizontally like `'test1', 'test2', 'test3'` .I want it vertically like

```
test1
test2
test3
```

The purpose of displaying the list vertically is I want to catch the selected value from that input text field. For Now i just stuck while displaying list vertically

```
public class accountController {
 public List<String> alphabet {get;set;}
    public accountController (){
      alphabet = new list<String>();
        alphabet.add('test1');
          alphabet.add('test2');
          alphabet.add('test3');
         
    }
}
```

Vf page

```
<apex:page Controller="accountController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="My Content" mode="edit">
           
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
                <apex:inputText  value="{!alphabet}"/>
     </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text fields do not allow multiple rows of text.

If you're trying to get multiple input fields, use a repeat tag somehow:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="My Content Section" columns="2">
  <apex:repeat items="{!alphabet}" var="item">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
      <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Value" for="input"/>
      <apex:inputText id="input" value="{!item}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Or if you want multiple lines of text in a single input:

```
<apex:inputTextArea value="{!alphabet}" />
```

However, the latter needs normal line breaks, not a list:

```
public String alphabet { get; set; }
public accountController() {
  alphabet = 'test1\ntest2\ntest3';
  // Or String.join(new String[] { 'test1','test2','test3' }, '\n');
}
```

Comment: it worked when I used ``apex:inputTextArea `` but how to select multiple values?

Comment: @Fawadazam Are you looking for a multi-select picklist, then?

Comment: can we only select multiple values multi-select picklist?? or in  ``apex:inputTextArea  ``?

Comment: @Fawadazam Hmm, let's back up a second. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Read about the [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) for an explanation of what I'm trying to get.